# What is the error with a Lisp a expression

Tags: runtime-error, lisp

I don't really know a thing about Lisp, but I already dislike it (sorry, Lisp peoples).  I need to describe what is wrong with the following statement:

```
(caar '(a (b c d)))
```

The error it throws is:

```
#<THREAD "interpreter" {4D62083F}>: Debugger invoked on condition of type TYPE-ERROR
  The value A is not of type LIST.
Restarts:
  0: TOP-LEVEL Return to top level.
```

But I need a detailed description of what exactly is going on.  Please help.

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say the problem is that `a` is not a list.

Comment: That is true from the error, but why is that a problem?

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: Ha!  I suppose I am cheating because this is a HW question.  Hope Prof isn't reading.  :) I don't really understand Lisp fundamentally and why the number of nested errors continues to increase every time I run it.

Comment: I guess it is used a lot in AI so maybe I should understand it more.

Comment: @Shawn So you might think, coming from a Lisp dialect with stricter list handling, but that is not so in Common Lisp, which allows `car` on the empty list. Historically, it was InterLisp which introduced this relaxation, and it was adopted by MacLisp. Notably, the relaxation is not found in Scheme, as well as older Lisps like Lisp 1.5.

Comment: @Kaz Common Lisp just gets stranger and stranger

Comment: @Shawn Without the ability to `car` and `cdr` on an empty list, and the empty list `nil` being Boolean false, simple code like `(cdr (assoc key alist))` becomes importunately verbose. Ashwin Ram, Ph. D., Technical Director of AI in the Office of the CTO for Google Cloud, wrote a [ballad about this back in 1986](https://ashwinram.org/1986/01/28/a-short-ballad-dedicated-to-the-growth-of-programs/).

Comment: @Kaz I generally want to report an error or otherwise specifically handle a case where `assoc` etc. can't find something anyways instead of just assuming. No extra verbosity then. (And nothing wrong with being verbose if it makes code clearer)

Comment: @Shawn That would only be in the case when your assoc list sometimes meaningfully stores `nil` as a value under a key, which is supposed to be treated differently from the key being absent. If you don't have this situation in your design then `(cdr (assoc key list))` yields a value (which is also Boolean true) or else `nil` which is false and means "not found". You will likely be testing **that**.   you can also do things like `(or (cdr assoc key main-list) (cdr assoc key fallback-list))` where we can factor out the `cdr`: `(cdr (or (assoc key main-list) (assoc key fallback-list)))`.

Comment: @Kaz `assoc` returns a pair or `#f` (`nil` in common lisp I guess). You check that **before** using `cdr` on it. And typically yes I'd want to treat an empty list cdr of said alist pair differently than not having the key present at all.

Comment: Your arguments seem to be coming from a programming style very alien to what I consider good practice.

Comment: @Shawn That's the style in Common Lisp and similar dialects. `nil` is often allowed to propagate to be checked in a higher level of nesting, which reduces the amount of checking code.  If you pepper your code with unnecessary nil checks in a team project, you will likely be called out on it, unless everyone is a Scheme programmer.

Answer (score 2):

`(caar x)` means the same thing as `(car (car x))`: applying `car` twice.

`(car '(a (b c d))` produces `a`.

The `car` of that doesn't make sense because `a` is not a cons cell, and is not the symbol `nil`.

`car` asks for the first element of a list, by means of asking for the car field of the first cons cell.

In ANSI Common Lisp, `car` is "forgiving" in the following way: you can ask for the first element of the empty list `nil`, which doesn't have any elements (or cons cells, so nothing with a *car field). Though there is no cons cell there, and so no car field, `car` takes that as a special case and returns `nil`. This little provision makes all sorts of list processing code shorter and easier to read.

Now, the symbol `a` isn't a list, and so you have a type error.

These uses of `caar` make sense:

```
(caar nil) -> nil     ;; (car nil) is nil; car of that is nil again.
(caar '(nil)) -> nil  ;; (car '(nil)) is nil; car of that is nil again
(caar '((a))) -> a    ;; (car '((a))) is (a), (car '(a)) is a.
```

Dialect note: not all Lisp dialects which have lists of cons cells allow `car` on the empty list. In Scheme, there is no `nil` symbol; the empty list is `()`, and must be quoted when used as an expression. `(car '())` is an error in Scheme.